# Update/overwrite Third party module which is installed in vendor folder

Tags: magento2, module, template, html

I have two extensions installed via composer and that is in vendor folder. I have done some customisation on those modules ie: updating the files in the `vendor/mymodule/` folder. Now after a Magento upgrade (2.3.2 to 2.3.5) all my changes are gone.

Any help to update/overwrite these files with creating my own module in app folder?

The files I have updated in the  folder are

vendor/module/view/frontent/layout/checkout_osc.xml
vendor/module/view/frontent/web/css/osc.css
vendor/module/view/frontent/web/template/view/shipping-address/address-render/osc.html
vendor/module/view/frontent/web/template/view/comment.html

Comment: check two link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264707/85907 2) https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252619/85907

Comment: Thanks! Got a solution with overriding the files in the app/design/frontend theme folder.

Comment: Welcome @ASR...